# Every Countable set has measure $0$

Tags: measure-theory

I came across the following lemma in some book:

Every countable set has measure $0$ and the proof involved "breaking" down the countable set into a countable union of points and then proved that every point has measure $0$ and hence by sub-additivity proved that a countable set has measure $0$, but am I right in assuming that this will only ever be true when we are talking about the Lebesgue measure? Because if we had instead defined the measure as a trivial measure then only the null set would have measure $0$

Comment: You are right, there are certainly measures that assign a positive number to a countable set. Consider for example Dirac measures.

Comment: You are correct: it is not true in general. Any measure with atoms will fail to have this property. However, there are measures  which are not equivalent to Lebesgue measure for which it still holds true. For example, the Cantor measure on $[0,1]$ is singular to Lebesgue measure, but it still has this property, surprisingly enough.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're almost right.

This is true for any measure which gives $0$ to singletons. It could be the Lebesgue measure, or some other regular Borel measure, or a measure giving $0$ to countable sets and $\infty$ to uncountable sets.

But of course, there can be measure which give to *some* singleton, or *some* countable set a positive measure. For example the measure $\mu(A)=\begin{cases} 0 & 1\notin A\\ 1 & 1\in A\end{cases}$ is such measure.